# Php base64_encode function for image gives output different from similar function in coreutils

Tags: php, image, base64

The following php code:

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents("test.jpeg"));
```

produces:

```
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
```

While I'm expecting to get what (linux) coreutils base64 produces for the same image:

```
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
```

How would I make php produce the same output as linux coreutils?

Comment: As Pierre pointed out the image was simply encoded twice. Still not sure how this came to be but the problem is now resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to base64decode the first line (`LzlqL...`) and it gives as result the `/9j/4...`. It seems you have something wrong somewhere and you have encoded twice the image

Comment: This solved the problem. Not sure why the string was double encoded nor why it only was double encoded for the image. Thanks