# convert base64 string into image in python

Tags: python, django, string, image, base64

I am trying to convert base64 string into image, so far I have been following this:
[How to convert base64 string to image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214190/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-image/16214280)
here is pas of the code

```
image = stringToRGB(request.POST.get("image", None))
#request.POST.get("image", None) = 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
```

```
def stringToRGB(base64_string):
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(str(base64_string))
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

the result is I get an error that say `"Incorrect padding"`
is there a way to solve this case ?

Second update

```
def stringToRGB(base64_string):
    base64_string += "=" * ((4 - len(base64_string) % 4) % 4)
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(str(base64_string))
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

error for second update:

```
cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x11ba2c400>
```

update 3

```
def stringToRGB(base64_string):
    # base64_string += "===" * ((4 - len(base64_string) % 4) % 4)
    altchars = b'+/'
    base64_string = re.sub(rb'[^a-zA-Z0-9%s]+' %
                           altchars, b'', base64_string)  # normalize
    missing_padding = len(base64_string) % 4
    if missing_padding:
        base64_string += b'=' * (4 - missing_padding)

    imgdata = base64.b64decode(str(base64_string), altchars)
    print(imgdata, ";;;;;;;;")
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    print(image, "////")
    return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

from third update I get an error: `cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object`

Comment: You will have to decode bas64 image like `base64_string.split(',')[1]`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941995/python-ignore-incorrect-padding-error-when-base64-decoding)?

Comment: @SreekantShenoy I update my question and I get another error like this ```"cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x11ba2c400>"``` is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you update the question with a complete base64 string, because the base64 image doesn't seem valid? You have online tools to check if its valid.

Comment: @SreekantShenoy here is the link for base64 string: https://gist.github.com/wahyu-handayani/3c754802631bb697f96d9189f8d6e07a, I have check it online to validate the base64 string and here is the result:```According to the specification, your string should have a padding character. This is optional, but sometimes it can lead to unexpected errors.```

Comment: That base64 string is not a valid image. Check [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962033/php-base64-encode-function-for-image-gives-output-different-from-similar-functio/48962081)

Comment: @SreekantShenoy, actually I get this base64 string from frontend (flutter) and then I send it using api python as backend for checking and evaluating, I will try to get another way to encode the image from flutter

Comment: Yeah, just make sure its valid.

Comment: @bad_coder I have tried the answer which have 84 upvote, but I get an error like this: ```cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object```. I also have tried for the rest of the answer there, but I still get another error

Comment: @bad_coder I update my question, would you like to take a look?

Comment: Looks like with your last update, you're using `b''` bytestrings in `re` but `base64_string` is a regular Unicode string.

Comment: @MarkRansom would you like to give an example to do that ?

Comment: Just remove the `b` from the front of the string constants: `base64_string = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9%s]+' % altchars, '', base64_string)`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I have tried it just now and got this message: ```can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str```

Comment: Probably because `altchars` is still a byte string.  Or maybe the `b'='` you have later. 
 You need to be consistent in your string types everywhere.